# Javascript join wrong when custom indexes

Tags: javascript

I have this array:

```
[10: "AAA", 30: "BBB", 50: "CCC", 60: "DDD", 80: "EEE", 81: "FFF", 82: "GGG", 83: "HHH"]
```

and after using command :

> myarray.join(' | ')

it will return multiple duplicated pipes. function `join` means that there is array with indexes 0-10, 11-29, etc. like : `[empty × 10, "AAA", empty × 19, "BBB", empty × 19, "CCC", empty × 9, "DDD", empty × 19, "EEE", "FFF", "GGG", "HHH"]`

Result is:

> |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | AAA |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 
>   |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | BBB |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
>   |  |  |  |  | CCC |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | DDD |  |  |  |  |  |  |
>   |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | EEE | FFF | GGG | HHH

but expected result is:

> AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD | EEE | FFF | GGG | HHH

How to join custom indexed array?

Comment: Filter the array before joining ..?

Comment: You get that result, because that's how the array actually looks like. The array has 83 entries, most of them are `undefined`, but the length of the array is 83. So you probably should think over using a Object or a Set instead of an Array.

Comment: this helped to me: myarray= myarray.filter(function(val){return val});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter` the blank or undefined entries and then join as normal.

```js
myarray = [];
myarray[10] = 'AAA'; myarray[30] = 'BBB'    
result = myarray.filter(x => x != '' && x != undefined).join('|')
console.log(result)
```

**Edit**:
For this particular case, `filter` can be simplified with:

```
result = myarray.filter(x => x).join('|')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could filter a sparse array with a callback which returns `true` and join the result.

```js
var array = [],
    result;

array[10] = "AAA";
array[30] = "BBB";
array[50] = "CCC";
array[60] = "DDD";
array[80] = "EEE";
array[81] = "FFF";
array[82] = "GGG";
array[83] = "HHH";
result = array.filter(_ => true).join('|');
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
let arr = [];
arr[10] = "AAA", arr[30] = "BBB", arr[50] = "CCC", arr[60] = "DDD", arr[80] = "EEE", arr[81] = "FFF", arr[82] = "GGG", arr[83] = "HHH";

let result = arr.filter(v => !!v).join('|');
console.log(result);
```